# Unlink chart from excel and keep data editable?

Tags: excel, vba, charts, powerpoint

for the longest of times I've been trying to achieve this to no avail. It seems like it should be a common problem but still I haven't been able find an answer. What I want to do is:

- Have a chart in Excel and/or Powerpoint.
- Copy this chart as a chart object into PPT.
- Keep all characteristics of the original chart but maintain it editable (i.e. - add/remove axes, data labels etc)
- Break the link to the original chart/workbook but **keep the data editable**. I.e., I want a new excel sheet opened when I want to edit the data, just like it works if I create a new chart object.

  - Preferably, I would like to convert the data of the original to this new chart sheet but this is not of really high importance.

Basically, I want to be able to use graphs as templates for a new graph without editing the original data. Please help!

PS. I didn't include any code as most of the code I've tried has tried to achieve something else. I mostly want to know if this is even possible to do (it should be!)?

Comment: Instead of copying the existing chart to powerpoint, could you instead copy the data to a new blank excel workbook, generate a chart in this workbook, save it to your desired location and then copy the new chart to Powerpoint with the link to your new excel workbook?

Comment: Well, I'm afraid not due to two things:

* Then I would have to recreate the whole chart from scratch, basically defeating the sole purpose for doing this.
* I would need to link to another sheet, which is not a good option if I want to send the file to others.

Comment: Here's a link that may help: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/568668-excel-visual-basic-applications-change-link-source-powerpoint-linked-objects.html Note that you will still have to get the users a template file to use, but this gets you part of the way there.

Comment: I used Kazimierz Jawor code for this [See Kazimierz break link code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15766803/7493266)

Comment: Jeez. 8 years later and still no solution to this... Once the link to the Excel is broken, I can still resize the chart and change the chart type but the Edit Data button is disabled.